# Julia GraphPlot package error

Tags: package, julia, precompiling

I'm trying to run a Julia code which works with GraphPlot package. I have already added this package to Julia. But I'm getting the following error when I start running the code. Can someone please help me with this?

> Failed to precompile GraphPlot to /Users/Tim/.julia/lib/v0.5/GraphPlot.ji.
>   while loading /Users/Tim/Dropbox/Python/Model/ip.jl, in expression starting on line 5

Comment: The error message is telling you that julia cannot precompile GraphPlot. There can be hundreds of reasons for that, but there is no way we can tell you if you don't post the entire message. Note though that the package doesn't appear to be compatible with julia-0.6 yet.

Comment: Thanks, Michael... but is there anything that we could do to fix this error?

Comment: Try and open an issue at the repo to ask what their plans are.

Comment: I see you're also having precompilation errors in Atom. Perhaps you should try to reinstall Julia afresh? There might be something wrong with your installation.

Comment: I fixed the issue bu reinstalling Julia... Thanks, Michael.